# Is there any way to create 2 x 2 array/matrix from a larger array/matrix

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix

New to Ruby and learning at the moment.

I am not sure I should use arrays or matrix for this.

I have arrays

```
[['J','O','I','J','O'],
 ['I','J','O','J','O'],
 ['I','I','J','I','J']]
```

I want to find out the following as you can see in the image.

```
['J', 'O']
['I', 'J']
```

[image]

What I thought was using Ruby Matrix, but I am not sure if I can divide the original array/matrix to chunk of small 2 by 2 matrix and if it matches with `[J, O], [I, J]`.

Or should I use array and loop through.

I appreciate any inputs.

Comment: I suggest you `require 'matrix'` and use the [Matrix#minor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor) method.

Comment: @sawa I am not able to read what you wrote. :(

Comment: I suggest you change `['J', 'O']['I', 'J']` to `[['J', 'O']['I', 'J']]` (on two lines) so that it is a valid array.  No need to reply, as I will delete this comments once you have seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the method [Matrix#minor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor) to do this.

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def find_in_matrix(arr,sub)
  sub_nrows = sub.size
  sub_ncols = sub.first.size
  rows      = Array[*0..arr.size-sub_nrows]
  cols      = Array[*0..arr.first.size-sub_ncols]
  arr_m     = Matrix[*arr]
  sub_m     = Matrix[*sub]
  rows.product(cols).select {|i,j| arr_m.minor(i,sub_nrows,j,sub_ncols)==sub_m}
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [['J','O','I','J','O'],
       ['I','J','O','J','O'],
       ['I','I','J','I','J']]

sub = [['J', 'O'],
       ['I', 'J']]

find_in_matrix(arr,sub)                    #=> [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 3]]
find_in_matrix(arr, [['O'], ['J']])        #=> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 4]]
find_in_matrix(arr, [['O']])               #=> [[0, 1], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 4]]
find_in_matrix(arr, [['I','J','O']])       #=> [[0, 2], [1, 0]]
find_in_matrix(arr, [['I','J'],['J','O']]) #=> []
find_in_matrix(arr, [[]])                  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1],...,[0, 5]] 
                                           #    [1, 0], [1, 1],...,[1, 5]]
                                           #    [2, 0], [2, 1],...,[2, 5]]
```

**Explanation**

For the example above:

```
sub_nrows = sub.size                              #=> 2
sub_ncols = sub.first.size                        #=> 2
rows      = Array[*0..(arr.size-sub_nrows)]       #=> [0, 1]
cols      = Array[*0..(arr.first.size-sub_ncols)] #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
arr_m     = Matrix[*arr]
  #=> Matrix[["J", "O", "I", "J", "O"], ["I", "J", "O", "J", "O"],
  #          ["I", "I", "J", "I", "J"]]
sub_m     = Matrix[*sub]
  #=> Matrix[["J", "O"], ["I", "J"]]

a = rows.product(cols)
  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
a.select {|i,j| arr_m.minor(i,sub_nrows,j,sub_ncols)==sub_m}
  #=> [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 3]]
```

Consider the first element of `a` that `select` passes into the block: `[0, 0]` (i.e., the block variables `i` and `j` are both assigned the value zero).  We therefore compute:

```
arr_m.minor(i,sub_nrows,j,sub_ncols) #=> arr_m.minor(0,2,0,2) 
  #=> Matrix[["J", "O"], ["I", "J"]]
```

As

```
arr_m.minor(0,2,0,2) == sub_m
```

`[0, 0]` is selected.  On the other hand, for the element `[1, 2]` of `a`, `i => 1, j => 2`, so:

```
arr_m.minor(i,sub_nrows,j,sub_ncols) #=> arr_m.minor(1,2,2,2) 
  #=> Matrix[["O", "J"], ["J", "I"]]
```

which does not equal `sub_m`, so the element `[1, 2]` is not selected.

Note that `Matrix#minor` has two forms.  I used the form that takes four parameters.  The other form takes two ranges as parameters.

Comment: This looks cleaner than using array!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It is very helpful for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks, shin.  I'm generally provide explanations, for the reason you mention.

Comment: What is arr.size-sub_nrows? Is size-sub_nrows? a method? Where does it come from?

Comment: According to doc example, #minor takes two param but yours have four params.

Comment: If you think of `arr` and `sub` as two-dimensional arrays, `arr.size - sub_nrows` => 3 - 2 = 1 is the last row (offset) of `arr` which can be the first row of `sub` and `arr.first.size-sub_ncols` => 5 - 2 = 3 is last column (offset) of `arr` which can be the first column of `sub`. `minor()` can take either the four parameters I used or two ranges.

Comment: Opps, - was minus. Thanks for following up.

Comment: I think `rows = Array[*0..(arr.size-sub_nrows)]` can be `rows = Array(0..(arr.size-sub_nrows))`

Comment: Try it, shin: `Array[1..3] #=> [1..3]`, `Array[*1..3] #=> [1, 2, 3]`.  The first creates an array consisting of a single element, namely, the range `1..3`.  That's why you need to "splat" the range, as `Array[*1..3]` is the same as `Array[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the following:

```
def find_in_matrix(matrix, target)
  (0..matrix.length-target.length).to_a.product(
    (0..matrix.first.length-target.first.length).to_a).select do |x, y|
    (0...target.length).to_a.product(
      (0...target.first.length).to_a).all? do |test_x, test_y|
      matrix[x+test_x][y+test_y] == target[test_x][test_y]
    end
  end
end

matrix = [["J", "O", "I", "J", "O"], 
          ["I", "J", "O", "J", "O"], 
          ["I", "I", "J", "I", "J"]]

target = [["J", "O"],
          ["I", "J"]]

find_in_matrix(matrix, target)
 => [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 3]]
```

This solution simply goes over all the sub-matrices of `matrix` with `target`'s size, and selects the ones that are equal to it.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly to answer the question, and not an efficient way to get the matched position:

```
matrix = [
  %w(J O I J O),
  %w(I J O J O),
  %w(I I J I J)
]

target = [
  %w(J O),
  %w(I J)
]

matrix.each_cons(target.length).each_with_index do |sub, row|
  sub.map{|a| a.each_cons(target[0].length).to_a}.tap do |sub|
    head = sub.shift
    head.zip(*sub).each_with_index do |m, col|
      if m == target
        puts "#{row}, #{col}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```